# One of the view is disappearing when table view cell is selected, while the other one is not. Why is this happening? Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having a table view cell in which there are two UIImageViews. When I am selecting the cell one of the image view is disappearing. I have done the following code, because of that 1 UIImage is not disappearing, but what can I do with the other.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
UIColor *color = self.imageView.backgroundColor;
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
if (selected){
    self.imageView.backgroundColor = color;
        }
}

-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
UIColor *color = self.imageView.backgroundColor;
[super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
if (highlighted){
    self.imageView.backgroundColor = color;
        }
}
```

I have implemented the above code in the .m file of my table view cell. Because of this one Image view is staying but the other is disappearing.

My DidSelect method is

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

}

Comment: can you show DidSelectCode

Comment: Show your DidSelectMethod and CellForRow and if possible, add image of your exact problem

Comment: i have edited the question with the didselectmethod

Comment: why you need [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; in didselect method?

Comment: i used it for making the selected blue colour to go